# Expressing a choice between entries in SQL

Tags: postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database

I'd like to express a choice between entries in SQL.

Let's say that **People** deal with **problems**. Hopefully **Geniuses** are here to help us find great **solutions** to them. Some of these solutions are good, some are bad. Consequently a person *must choose the one* that fits best with his needs.

In order to express this *choice*, I found two way of doing this:

1) Using a boolean field named *is_chosen* in the *solutions* table. If a solution is chosen, the field is set as true.

[image: Solution 1]

2) Using a second association between the *problems* and *solutions* tables. By default, this extra foreign key is set as null because no solution has been chosen yet. This allows a problem to only have one unique solution but implies another association between both entities.

[image: Solution 2]

In your opinion, which one of these two alternatives is the most cost efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with the first one. Why? One, because the second solution creates a circular reference hindering you from using sql server's built in pk/fk update/delete capabilities. And if you are looking to use an ORM, they don't support circular references. Two, because real life questions rarely have one best solution. Geniuses will come up with many solutions and having the capability to mark/rate those solutions on more than criterion will be helpful. Three, cost effective...are you referring to the cost effectiveness of reading data or writing data? It's a tradeoff. SQl engines are very smart and unless you are planning to have > 100 million rows in your tables and not planning on  maintaining indexes, the difference will not be noticeable, neither in reads, nor in writes.

Comment: Jejew91 is not using SQL Server.